# Remove white spaces between img

Tags: html, css, whitespace, separator

i'm using blogger and I want to know how can I remove the white spaces between a img and a text, because is a lot separated. Blogger contains a class called separator but I don't know what to do for fix that.

Here's a image:

[image]

How can I remove it?

This is my css

```
.separator{ 
   margin: 0; 
   display: block; 
   padding: 0; 
} 
.post img { 
   display: block; 
   text-align: center; 
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px; 
}
```

CSS

```
/* Posts-----------------------------------------------*/
h2.date-header{margin:1.5em 0 .5em;display:none;}
.wrapfullpost{display: block;}
.post{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
.post img {display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.post-title{color:#333333;margin:0 0 10px 0;padding:0;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;font-size:24px;line-height:24px;font-weight:bold;}
.post-title a,.post-title a:visited,.post-title strong{display:block;text-decoration:none;text-decoration:none;}
.post-title strong,.post-title a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
.post-body{

    font-size: 17px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
.entry-content{ padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block;
}
.separator{
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}
.post-footer{margin:5px 0; font-weight: 300;}
.comment-link{margin-$startSide:.6em}
.postmeta-primary{color:#999;font-size:12px;line-height:18px;padding:0 0 5px 0}
.postmeta-secondary{color:#999;font-size:12px;line-height:18px;padding:0 0 10px 0}
.postmeta-primary span,.postmeta-secondary span{padding:3px 0 3px 20px;background-position:left center;background-repeat:no-repeat}
.meta_date{background-image:url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-paWPYJvQDqA/UC7eiuIKgUI/AAAAAAAAAvw/af410sUcO2w/s000/date.png)}
.meta_author{background-image:url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-reTaoyVmDXA/UC7ejgVBQbI/AAAAAAAAAv4/u6d-iPeLZi0/s000/author.png); border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
padding-right: 10px!important;
m
argin-right: 5px;}
.meta_comments{background-image:url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zZgvwATiF3E/UC7ej-cvmbI/AAAAAAAAAwA/THMs0579MII/s000/comments.png) }
.meta_edit{background-image:url(images/edit.png)}
.meta_categories{background-image:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-g-ptS39XbNM/UC7ekTJsEXI/AAAAAAAAAwI/t8fMhUuUvQI/s000/category.png)}
.meta_tags{background-image:url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-fZuK3yymXmo/UC7ek6kEDLI/AAAAAAAAAwQ/-J16r4bHvFo/s000/tags.png)}
.readmore{margin-bottom:5px;float:right}
.readmore a{color:#F85B48;background:#EAEAEA url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-m6AJDK0k2xA/UC7emOYbEbI/AAAAAAAAAwY/Q4o73QiZdc4/s000/readmore-bg.png) left top repeat-x;padding:8px 14px;display:inline-block;font-size:12px;line-height:12px;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase}
.readmore a:hover{color:#fff;background:#E74F3D url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-m6AJDK0k2xA/UC7emOYbEbI/AAAAAAAAAwY/Q4o73QiZdc4/s000/readmore-bg.png) left -126px repeat-x;text-decoration:none}
```

And this is what blogger add in HTML

```
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-DGgnyTkp3xc/VAtkSdWZLxI/AAAAAAAAAb4/oXctHDcrSRk/s1600/Sinopsis%2Bwissar.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-DGgnyTkp3xc/VAtkSdWZLxI/AAAAAAAAAb4/oXctHDcrSRk/s1600/Sinopsis%2Bwissar.png" height="160" width="640" /></a></div>
```

Comment: Please try: .separator { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

Comment: Give us an example page link or html code please

Comment: This is my css
.separator{
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}
.post img {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;

}

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't share any of your code, It's hard to explain where is the problem (You may get negative rep).
but i can suggest you to look at your style classes. try following, it's just a removal of Padding, and Margin

```
.imageClass{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
}

.textClass{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: As a note; it is impossible to get negative rep; if they have rep, they'll lose it, but not beyond 1.

Comment: I have this on the css
.separator{ 
   margin: 0; 
   display: block; 
   padding: 0; 
} 
.post img{ 
   display: block; 
   text-align: center; 
   padding: 0px; 
   margin: 0px; 
}

Comment: @AbdelPosada can you post exact code in Fiddle. because Screenshot will not actually help. but i think something is adding after your margin.

Comment: @Kirk added css and html

Answer (score 0):

Within the `seperator` class there is a `blockquote` which contains the text, and an `a` tag which is a link containing the image. Both of these have margins that you do not want. Try this.

```
.seperator blockquote {
    margin: 0px;
}

.seperator a {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Note: Remove what was in my previous answer.

If you can't get it to work, go to the section on your webpage that you want to change, right click -> inspect element. This will bring up the HTML inspector. You can then click on different elements and see the css on the right hand side that relates to that element. Try unticking different css statements or changing them/adding new ones. Just continue to play around with it until you can get it. I really can't be of any more help.

[image]

Comment: The image just disappears if I do that D:

Comment: Can you post your HTML or a link to the webpage please?

Comment: Where abouts is the section you want help with?

Comment: The space between even the text or an image and a text

Comment: Still having the same result :S

Comment: Did you remove the first suggestion in my answer?

Comment: No, I have .separator, .separator blcokquote and .separator a

Comment: Ok. Remove what I told you to add the first time. You only want `.seperator blockquote` and `.seperator a`. I've updated my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Same result :/ I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help anymore. I have added another update letting you know how you can debug this error yourself.

Comment: problem solved I just added `line-height:0; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0;` to `.separator` and keep the tags `a` and `blockquote` to separator, within those tags even with line-height:0 was the same result TY so much. :) BTW isn't seperator it's separator :P

Answer (score 0):

Solved, just added the next

```
.separator {
    display: block;
    line-height:0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.separator blockquote {
    margin: 0;
}

.separator a {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Thanks to Yep_It's_Me who helped me a lot.